# Require reason for post deletion and un-deletion?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, vote-to-delete

Could we have a method of explaining why we think a question or answer should be deleted?

It could work identically to closing a question, maybe with an additional text-input box (like the "Requires Moderator attention" flag option) to provide additional info because the reasons for deletion should really be more specific..

For example, "exact duplicate" doesn't explain to me the user has re-posted the same question, thus, it should definitely be deleted (not just left closed). Like with close-messages, these reasons would be listed under the deleted item (or answer).

I don't think comments are suitable, as they can be a pain to quickly.. "extract" deletion reasons from them - I have to scan through the comments, and they may all be irrelevant.

Equally, for un-deletion, it'd be useful to know why another user thinks a question should be restored. For example "new user deleted the question after they accepted an answer", or "Jeff went insane and started deleting any questions with the letter O in it".

I think requiring un-deletion reasons is possibly *more* important, since commenting is disabled on deleted questions - we have no way of explaining why we think it should be restored

Comment: I thought I remembered reading somewhere that there were plans to add annotation to posts so that people could add information like this, but I've had a difficult time finding where I read it, and I'm starting to doubt that I read it at all. Hopefully someone else will know what I'm talking about.

Comment: I think this would also be a good idea for users deleting their *own* answered questions or upvoted answers (should be required except for high-rep users).