# Can I see my own answer's deletion reason?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete

Can I see or be informed of deletion request reason(s)?

On sites where I have deletion request privileges, for someone else's post, I can click on the "delete (n)" link and see what's been suggested (and then cancel if I was only looking).

I have one deletion request for an answer on a site where I don't have deletion request privileges. In this specific case I don't care much about the answer -- it also has a current score of -1 (and no comments) -- but I noticed I can't find out what the reason for the deletion request is.

For questions, close reasons are reported to the OP so they may attempt to fix the problem. I believe that same opportunity should be offered to answerers.

Comment: Close reasons are given so the question can be improved; deleted answers are usually supposed to stay deleted. Still, it would provide good feedback for future answers.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I'm talking about answers that haven't been deleted yet (although I assume the outcome of my suggestion will be up to 5 reasons listed in the Inbox, or whatever, if an answer is deleted).

Comment: I assume you mean deleting from the VLQ review queue? If so, please edit your question to reflect this. 20K users can vote to delete answers with negative score without any comment and the process is different. (no review involved, 3 votes are enough etc)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know where the delete request came from (that's the point :-) ). [This](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30634/keeping-a-string-secret-in-open-source-code/38028#38028) is the answer I'm referring to.

Comment: oops, if you can see the (1) next to delete it means one thing: 20k rep user cast a vote. In this case, comment is only optional same way as comments for downvotes. When done via review, you don't see anything until the answer gets actually deleted (if it gathered 6 "Recommend Deletion" votes)

Comment: Anyway, your request looks like a dupe of [this older request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/940/require-reason-for-post-deletion-and-un-deletion), and here is [another related request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195606/also-show-add-a-comment-for-the-author-selection-when-deleting-voting-to-delet).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Perhaps that means (unfortunately) that I shouldn't be warned of the possible deletion until it occurs :-(

Comment: It's the same as downvotes, in my opinion. The fact you can see the pending delete vote means something is utterly wrong with the post. Unlike downvote, single or couple of delete votes have no effect though.

Comment: I've voted to close this (my) question as a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195606/also-show-add-a-comment-for-the-author-selection-when-deleting-voting-to-delet) because I agree that it should be optional to provide feedback. I was just under the impression there was a user interface used to choose which vote-to-delete option and so I could also view that, forgetting that that interface _does_ convert into comments when they're selected.